# Getting "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" when trying to update state variable onChange

Tags: reactjs, onchange, use-state

Good day I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm getting "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" let me explain:

I have a CustomUpload component:

```
export const CustomUpload = ({ name, children, accept, onChange, value }) => {
  const fileUpload = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fileUpload.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <div className="custom-upload-container">
      <label
        style={{ textAlign: "center", fontFamily: "var(--montserrat-text)" }}
        htmlFor={name}
      >
        {children}
      </label>
      <div className="custom-upload-input-container">
        <p>{value.name}</p>
        <div className="input-container">
          <input
            ref={fileUpload}
            className="custom-upload"
            type="file"
            name={name}
            accept={accept}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
        </div>

        <CustomButton onClick={handleClick}>Browse</CustomButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then I have a page where a user has to submit 5 images, but for simplicity sake I will use two:

```
export const Images = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState({
    image1: "",
    image2: "",
  });
const { image1, image2 } = data;

const handleOnChange = (value, fieldName) => {
setData({...data, [fieldName]: value });

return(
<form>
        <CustomUpload
          name="image1"
          onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.files[0], "image1")}
          value={image1}
          accept="image/*"
        >
          First Image
        </CustomUpload>
        <CustomUpload
          name="image2"
          onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.files[0], "image2")}
          value={image2}
          accept="image/*"
        >
          Second Image
        </CustomUpload>
</form>

}
```

The problem is that when I select the image it is giving me the error and I can't seem to figure out how I am supposed to solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. So the issue was that I was assigning the value of the CustomUpload using the value prop, which is normal for text input, but seems to break a file input.

```
<CustomUpload
          name="image1"
          onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.files[0], "image1")}
      >>> value={image1} //remove this line.
          accept="image/*"
        >
          First Image
</CustomUpload>
```

Should be:

```
<CustomUpload
          name="image1"
          onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.files[0], "image1")}
          accept="image/*"
        >
          First Image
</CustomUpload>
```

Btw this is a really neat solution for handling multiple file uploads and having a single onChangeHandler and useState hook. Hope this helps people out :D

Comment: But, when you reset the form, the value won't be change at all, the input will keep showing the same file.

Comment: @SalahAdDin in your submitHandler you can clear the data stored in your state variable.

Comment: it was not working for me.

Comment: Thanks! right to the spot! I was trying to set the file name by changing the element value, with no success.